# PHP Debugger with Unit Testing

Tags: phpunit, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I have gotten the Zend debugger to work with PDT 2.1. On the project I'm working on, I do unit testing with PHPUnit but running the debugger won't catch any of the breakpoints until I make some instances of the test class and then run the tests manually.

This is an issue, as I'd like to have the code base remain independent of the unit testing or debugging tools. Is it possible to debug my unit tests while not changing the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is switching to xdebug an option? I use xdebug to step through my PHPUnit tests without problem.